# Why is rotateY (flip) css3 animation flickering in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, css, webkit, css-transitions, vendor-prefix

I have made a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Grezzo/JR2Lu/

When you hit the i key on your keyboard, the picture flips around to show some text, but during the flip animation it flickers (particularly the text flickers) when viewed in Chrome.

(note that I am using -prefix-free JS library so that I don't have to prefix with browser specific CSS properties.)

Why is it flickering and how can I stop it?

UPDATE: Flicker is noticable on Chrome 20.0.1132.47 m running on XP, and whatever the latest version for OS X 10.7.4 Lion is (I'm not near my Mac right now to check)

Comment: Works fine here, Chrome 18 on Linux (ALWAYS mention the browser version when you're asking about browser-specific issues).

Comment: @RobW Good point - browser versions added.

Comment: That is very weird – same for me on my Mac. I wrote a tutorial about this, and have never seen this behaviour...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, this is a little weird. By removing the `background-color` from `.card`, it works OK: http://jsfiddle.net/JR2Lu/3/

Seems that styling `.card` is the issue, probably as you don't normally see that div.

Comment: Sir, you are a genius. I had previously encountered your tutorial (http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/all/), and have referred back to it many times. It has been very helpful, thank you.

Comment: Nice find! My faces have some more content and styling, it apparently doesn't flicker where there's no background or image, but that limits the effect to trivial use cases :(

Comment: any news on using the flip effect with background colors? I experience the same problem!

Comment: From memory the problem here was that a div was styled that shouldn't have been – the .card div is just a holder, and isn't mean to be styled – just style the faces.