# CSS3 rotating flip card - flickering?

Tags: css, rotation, transition, flicker

See the grey box on this page: http://goo.gl/fL973

When you hover it it's suppose to flip over and show the other side. It works in Chrome, but for some reason i'm getting a lot of flickering during the animation. I tried fiddling around with the rules and even adding a container around the box, but no success.

I read this question, among others: [Why is rotateY (flip) css3 animation flickering in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296028/why-is-rotatey-flip-css3-animation-flickering-in-chrome)

The problem seems to be that elements with `backface-visibility: hidden;` cannot have backgrounds. So, as a workaround, i thought i could have an element inside `.front` and `.back` and give that element a background. That didn't work, still flickered.

Other than that, i'm also not sure why it only works in Chrome/webkit. I do have the necessary prefixes for everything, so it should work, shouldn't it?

Any suggestions?

Comment: The original example is no longer available.

Comment: @2C-B Ah yes, the site went live. Here you go: http://goo.gl/twrXGI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works fine after moving the `backface-visibility: hidden;` to the `.front` and `.back` instead of `.card`. The flickering disappeared. Now i'll just have to come up with some fallback for non supporting browsers.